# How do I set different connection strings for Azure Cloud Services when deployed from TFS

Tags: azure, tfs, tfsbuild

I am trying to setup essentially a Development, Staging and Production cloud service. So far I have setup 2 cloud services:

- MyApp - which is what I am hoping to have be the staging and production since they have the same connection string and should be identical and the ability to quickly swap VIP is a nice feature.
- MyAppDev - I want this to point to our development database.

I also want to do the continuous build integration from tfspreview to azure. This is working great except for making the connection string unique.

So far I have setup the cloud services and have it doing continuous builds. I have also set my connection string in web.config and web.production.config. In addition I have setup publishing profiles (.azurePubxml) files and set them to be the Alternative Publish Profile in the build definition process section. These publish profiles specify which config to use (or at least that is what I thought). It seems to pick up the settings for the publish profile because I have RDP enabled and such with different passwords.

So how can I make the build controller use the "Production" & "Debug" build configurations to pickup the web.config transformations?

Hope that makes sense.

EDIT:

I only have Solution to build as seen below:

[image]

Comment: Are you doing CI via Web Deploy? or republishing the Azure package each time?

Sections 5 and/or 6 of the build process should pick up the right version of what you want to deploy depending on what you've set in the .azurePubxml definition once it goes to deploy the package.

So, are you saying its not doing that?

Comment: I am using CI to deploy via the settings in the azurePubxml. It is picking up settings that I have in my azurePubxml except for the Build Configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining your build definition, in the "Process" section under item 1. "Items to Build" you are given the opportunity of defining which configuration to Build. In here, type the name of the configuration that matches your .config definition to build that version.

[image: Build Definition Configuration]

EDIT: This is a little late, but this is how I got the alternate configuration to build along with the correct connection strings. I set the MSBuild Argument for configuration manually and my build correctly changed the connection strings on deployment to Azure.

[image: Advanced Build Options]

Comment: I only have Solution to build not Items to Build. I have included a screen shot in my original description.

Comment: Ya, my screenshot was for the default build template. I didn't know you were using the AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml template.

Comment: I get this error in my build

Production | Any CPU
1 error(s), 1 warning(s)
$/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp.sln - 1 error(s), 1 warning(s)
C:\a\src\MyApp\MyApp.sln.metaproj (0): The target "MyApp_Azure:Publish" does not exist in the project.
Other Errors
1 error(s)
Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException) Exception Stack Trace: at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstanc

Answer (score 0):

Just set your downloaded Azure publishing profile in section 6. "Web Deploy Publishing Profile". It's not necessary to use different web.config files Connection String will be rewritten on publish build runtime.